# Installing newer version of Ubuntu

Tags: installation

I have a older model IBM Think-pad and I have successfully installed Ubuntu 9.04 and found that it is no longer supported. I have burned a copy of 12.10 onto a CD and tried without installing onto a desktop. When I have placed the same cd into the Think-pad, it does not recognize there is anything on the cd such as the OS. Are there any suggestions

Comment: Was it a brand new CD, and was it large enough to hold the whole .iso? Obviously if you didn't manage to fit the whole image on there it won't work properly, but I've noticed that you can't seem to boot from a DVD/CD that has previously had something burned on it, even if you reformat it.

Answer (score 0):

The CD has to be burned so that it is bootable ([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)). If you did that, then perhaps the BIOS is not configured to boot a CD ([link](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Bios-to-Boot-from-a-CD-ROM)).

Alternative to a CD, you can boot and install from a USB ([link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)). The BIOS will similarly have to be configured to boot a USB drive before the hard drive with the existing operating system.